# how to convert from ascii code to normal code in python?

Tags: python, performance, ascii

I'm almost new in python and i want to solve a question,which is the AlphabetRunEncryption(str) function,that read the str parameter being passed which will be an encrypted string and the output should be the original decrypted string.
Now I need a function or a fast and easy method to convert from ascii code to normal code(convert ascii code to it's alphabet)

Comment: What is your desire output?

Comment: `AlphabetRunEncryption` is not part of Python. Is it something you are defining? Python has a function [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) which converts a character to its ASCII code.

Comment: Do you mean, you want such an `f` that `f(ord('a')) == f(ord('A')) == 1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in function [`chr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) will convert an ascii code to the corresponding character.

Example:

```
>>> chr(65)
'A'
```